# BigQuery's QUALIFY Clause Access Columns differently based on the Position of Window function?

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm working with BigQuery and came across the QUALIFY clause, which I understand can be used for filtering results based on window functions. However, I noticed some nuances in terms of how the QUALIFY clause accesses columns, especially depending on the position of the window definition.

Can someone clarify how the QUALIFY clause operates in relation to columns from the FROM clause and SELECT list aliases?

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery's SQL, there are two types of columns:

1. Columns available via the FROM clause.
2. Columns as SELECT list aliases.

The behaviour of the QUALIFY clause varies based on where the window function is located. Let's dive into your examples to clarify, using the following dataset a:

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(1 AS val, 'in' AS position),
    (2, 'out'),
    (3, 'above'),
    (1, 'in')
    ])
)
```

###### Scenario 1: define the window function inside the SELECT list

When you define the window function inside the SELECT list, QUALIFY only has access to columns available via the FROM clause.

Example 1.1: This is a valid query because the QUALIFY clause is filtering based on the rn column, which is derived from the position column present in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN position = 'above' THEN 'in'
    ELSE position
    END AS mapped_position,
    val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER w1 as rn,
FROM a
QUALIFY rn = 1
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY position)
```

Example 1.2: This query below is invalid. While QUALIFY tries to filter based on the rn column, the window function uses mapped_position, which is an alias from the SELECT list. Thus, it can't access mapped_position at this point.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN position = 'above' THEN 'in'
    ELSE position
    END AS mapped_position,
    val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER w1 as rn,
FROM a
QUALIFY rn = 1
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY mapped_position)
```

###### Scenario 2: define the window function directly within the QUALIFY clause

When you define the window function directly within the QUALIFY clause, it has access to both columns from the FROM clause and columns as SELECT list aliases.

Example 2.1: This is a valid query. QUALIFY filters based on a window function that partitions by the `position` column from the FROM clause.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN position = 'above' THEN 'in'
    ELSE position
    END AS mapped_position,
    val
FROM a
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY position) = 1
```

Example 2.2: This query is valid, the window function is defined in QUALIFY, with partition by mapped_position, which is an alias in the SELECT list. So, it could access `mapped_position` at this point.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN position = 'above' THEN 'in'
    ELSE position
    END AS mapped_position,
    val
FROM a
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mapped_position) = 1
```

In summary, the position of the window definition affects the columns that the QUALIFY clause can access. When defining window functions inside the SELECT list, QUALIFY can only access columns from the FROM clause. However, when window functions are defined directly in QUALIFY, it can access both the columns from the FROM clause and the aliases defined in the SELECT clause.

Knowing that, take a guess, what result would this SQL return?

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM UNNEST(
        [STRUCT(1 AS val, 'in' AS position),
        (2, 'out'),
        (3, 'above'),
        (1, 'in')
        ])
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN position = 'above' THEN 'in'
    ELSE position
    END AS position,
    val
FROM a
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY position) = 1
```